# Issue With SQL Insert From CSV

Tags: kotlin, csv, android-sqlite

I have an issue with my code funcitonallity. Im trying to get android studio kotlin code to scan each CSV file row and check if the cooridantaes in the row match the current user coordinates. If so, then the row will be inserted into an SQL. Here is the code:

```
private fun isWithin100Miles(
    userLat: Double,
    userLng: Double,
    dataLat: Double,
    dataLng: Double
): Boolean {
    val R = 6371.0 // Earth's radius in kilometers

    val lat1 = Math.toRadians(userLat)
    val lon1 = Math.toRadians(userLng)
    val lat2 = Math.toRadians(dataLat)
    val lon2 = Math.toRadians(dataLng)

    val dlat = lat2 - lat1
    val dlon = lon2 - lon1

    val a = Math.sin(dlat / 2) * Math.sin(dlat / 2) +
            Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) *
            Math.sin(dlon / 2) * Math.sin(dlon / 2)

    val c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))

    val distance = R * c // Distance in kilometers

    val milesPerKilometer = 0.621371
    val distanceInMiles = distance * milesPerKilometer
    Log.d("DBHelper", "Checking Distance:")

    return distanceInMiles <= 100
}
```

// ...

```
private fun insertNationalDataFromCSV(db: SQLiteDatabase, context: Context) {
    try {
        val inputStream = context.assets.open("crash_data - Copy.csv")
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

        reader.readLine() // Skip header

        val batchSize = 2
        var batchCount = 0

        val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        Log.d("DBHelper", "start function insertnatinoaldata:")

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            val location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

            val userLat = location?.latitude ?: 0.0
            val userLng = location?.longitude ?: 0.0

            db.beginTransaction()
            while (true) {
                val line: String? = reader.readLine()

                if (line == null) {
                    break
                }

                val columns = line.split(",")

                if (columns.size > 3) {
                    val severity = columns[1].toInt()
                    val startLat = columns[3].toDouble()
                    val startLng = columns[4].toDouble()

                    // Check if the data is within 100 miles of the user's current location
                    if (isWithin100Miles(userLat, userLng, startLat, startLng)) {
                        db.execSQL(
                            "INSERT INTO $TABLE_NAME_NATIONAL " +
                                    "($COLUMN_SEVERITY, $COLUMN_START_LAT, $COLUMN_START_LNG) " +
                                    "VALUES ($severity, $startLat, $startLng)"
                        )
                    }

                    batchCount++
                    if (batchCount >= batchSize) {
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful()
                        db.endTransaction()
                        db.beginTransaction()
                        batchCount = 0
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("DBHelper", "Invalid CSV format for National data: $line")
                }
            }


            db.setTransactionSuccessful()
        } else {
            Log.e("DBHelper", "Location permission not granted")
        }

        reader.close()
        inputStream.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("DBHelper", "Error opening CSV file for National data: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

I tried a couple of things. First, I tried using while loops for scanning the rows in the CSV. Next, I tried adding logs, which only one log showed up in logcat. Finally, I tried AI Bard and ChatGPT 3.5, to which none could find the problem or produce working solutions.